# What does "Wakanda" actually do?

Tags: munchkin

Wakanda, from the Marvel Munchkin DC expansion pack Mystic Mayhem, states that no monster can enter combat (via wandering monster, ect.). What exactly does this mean?

Can you use a replicate card, which states another monster appears, to add another monster to combat? Does it just mean you cannot play an actual monster card?

Comment: The full text from the card would make it easier to answer... I *assume* that Wakanda is a monster card, but answering based on guesswork often doesn't turn out well.

Answer (score 3):

As Replicate is just the Marvel Munchkin version of the Mate card, if you take a look at the [FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/) (search for 'is Mate an enhancement card') you'll see that it works like a Wandering Monster card and adds an additional monster.

This means that the Wakanda dungeon prevents players from playing either a  Wandering Monster or Replicate (or Mate if you're playing with non-marvel as well).